# The view ProjectManagementapp.views.product_insert_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

"I'm going to make a project but getting httpresponse error in my code, what should i do for it?"

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ProductData
from  .forms import productInsertform,productdeleteform,ProductUpdateForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request,'ProjectManagementapp/product_home.html')

def product_insert_view(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        iform = productInsertform(request.POST)

        if iform.is_valid():

            Product_id1 = request.POST.get('product_id','')
            Product_name1 = request.POST.get('product_name', '')
            Product_cost1 = request.POST.get('product_cost', '')
            Product_color1 = request.POST.get('product_color', '')
            Product_class1= request.POST.get('product_class', '')
            Customer_name1 = request.POST.get('customer_name', '')
            Customer_mobile1 = request.POST.get('customer_mobile', '')
            Customer_email1 = request.POST.get('customer_email', '')
            data = ProductData(
                product_id=Product_id1,
                product_name=Product_name1,
                product_cost=Product_cost1,
                product_color=Product_color1,
                product_class=Product_class1,
                customer_name=Customer_name1,
                customer_email=Customer_email1,
                customer_mobile=Customer_mobile1,
            )

            data.save()
            iform = productInsertform()
            return render(request,'ProjectManagementapp/product_insert.html',{'iform':iform})


    else:
            iform = productInsertform()
            return render(request,'ProjectManagementapp/product_insert.html',{'iform':iform})
```

Comment: What if the method is a `POST` but the form is not valid? RIght now you do not return any response...

Comment: `if iform.is_valid():` ... where is the `else:` ? . btw the form you send is not valid, and the get sentences like: `request.POST.get('  customer_email', '')` are completely wrong, do not set spaces between `'` unless your variable name contains those spaces too. The else you have is not at the level of the `is_valid()` sentence.

Comment: I write else below data save() is it wrong? if it is wrong so where i write else in the code and u explain your answer in detail-@Evhz